# Selecting same item in 2 list boxes - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, listbox

So I have 2 listboxes, for an example I'll use the names Jack, John and Joe.
All three names are in 2 listboxes each, I want to be able to select Jack and then have it select Jack in the second listbox. 
Is this possible? If so, would someone be able to help me??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms, and that you're storing simple strings in your listboxes, and the order might be different:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i As Integer = ListBox2.FindString(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    If (i <> -1 AndAlso ListBox2.SelectedIndex <> i) Then
        ListBox2.SelectedIndex = i
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i As Integer = ListBox1.FindString(ListBox2.SelectedItem)
    If (i <> -1 AndAlso ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> i) Then
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = i
    End If
End Sub
```

---------- Edit ----------

Given the change in ListBox contents, try this out:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim lb1 As ListBox = If(sender Is ListBox1, ListBox1, ListBox2)
    Dim lb2 As ListBox = If(sender Is ListBox1, ListBox2, ListBox1)

    If lb1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim number As String = lb1.SelectedItem.ToString.Split().Last
        For i As Integer = 0 To lb2.Items.Count - 1
            If lb2.Items(i).ToString.StartsWith(number) Then
                If lb2.SelectedIndex <> i Then
                    lb2.SelectedIndex = i
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the same handler is handling both the ListBox1 and ListBox2 SelectedIndexChanged() events.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to make it select ("1 Jack") in listbox2 when it says ("Jack 1") in listbox1?

Comment: Sure...but what is the **pattern** we are looking for here?  What do the other entries look like?  Need more examples before I can make a suggestion...

Comment: I'm having 1 listbox that will have a name then phone number e.g("Jack 035839033") and the second listbox will have the phone number then name e.g("035839033 Jack"). It's for sorting purposes but I need to be able to select someone in the first listbox and have it highlight the one with the same characters in the second. The other entries will just be peoples names and phone numbers.

Comment: Is there a way to do it so that when I click the item in listbox1 it activates a search function which looks for an item with the exact same letters in listbox2 then highlights it?

Comment: Dim countTime As Integer = (lstTime.Items.Count - 1)
        Dim wordsTime As String
        For a = 0 To countTime
            wordsTime = lstTime.Items.Item(a)
            If InStr(wordsTime.ToLower, TextBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
                lstTime.SelectedItem = wordsTime
            End If
        Next
LIke this but instead of searching for the letters in the textbox it uses the letters that were selected in listbox1